# I can't run a simple search with multiple search parameters using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have been trying to make a simple search but with more than one search parameters but can't really get ahead of it. am using sequelize 4.X and NodeJs.

Well, i tried receiving those search parameters via `req.params` after receiving them i do object destructing ( which normally works with just one parameter). I also tried to send  search parameters via req.body but after getting them and passing them to sequelize an invalid value error

```
//controller
static async getParticulars(req, res) {
        try {
            const one = await termService.getOneComplex(req.body.id,req.body.term,req.body.studentId,req.body.course);
            if (!one) {
                util.setError(400, "Term can't be found");
                return util.send(res);
            } else {
                util.setSuccess("Term found", 200, one);
                return util.send(res);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            util.setError(400, error.message);
            return util.send(res);
        }
    }
```

```
//service
static async getOneComplex(classId_n,term_n,studentId_n,course_n){
        try {
            const foundTerm = await database.Term.findAll({
                where :{
                    [op.and] : [
                        {classId:classId_n},
                        {studentId:studentId_n},
                        {term:term_n},
                        {course:course_n}
                    ]
                }
            });
            if(Object.values(foundTerm).length >=1){
                return foundTerm;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Expectations :
return an object with status,message,data( with actual data) properties.

```
//Actual:

{
    "status": "Error",
    "message": "Invalid value { classId: undefined }"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use operators here. Just use simple hash in where clause.

```
 const foundTerm = await database.Term.findAll({
                where :{
                        classId:classId_n
                        studentId:studentId_n
                        term:term_n
                        course:course_n
                       }   
            });
```

Further, According to your error. You are sending undefined as the value for classId. So log that value and check why it is undefined.